# Uso de PUT o PATCH en un mismo recurso según URI usada

Tags: spring, rest, restful

Estoy desarrollando una API RESful con java en Spring y me surgió una duda.

Tengo expuestas unas APIs para el recurso usuario (/users), el id de usuario lo obtengo por el token jwt por lo que en las URI que expongo en ese ejemplo me salto el id para el recurso (en vez de /users/1/displayName utilizo /users/displayName). Tengo clara la nomenclatura a utilizar para acceder a los recursos, por ejemplo, GET a la raiz para obtener el usuario, /users/displayname si quisiera obtener el nombre de usuario etc.

El tema es, para realizar una actualización parcial del recurso usuario debería usar el método PATCH e igual he visto que se hace mediante JSON indicando la acción, la ruta al recurso y el valor según corresponda pero mi problema es que en este recurso concreto no quiero que se actualicen más de dos campos (profileImage y displyName) por lo que el uso del JSON "genérico" lo veo demasiado tedioso.

Se me ocurrió entonces exponer dos métodos PATCH, users/displayName y users/profileImage pero claro, ahora la URI indica que no se está accediendo al recurso user sino al recurso dislpayName de user, entonces, ¿no debería convertirse en un método PUT al tratarse de una actualización completa del recurso al que se hace referencia en la URI?

Comment: Dudo que exista una respuesta correcta. Mi opinión es que NO, la entidad es USER, `displayName` o `profileImage` indican la propiedad ha actualizar,  son el argumento, perfectamente tu URL podría tener esta forma /users/1?campo=displayName y sería lo mismo, pero aquí no estarías dudando. Piénsalo de este modo, en tu base de datos vas a actualizar la tabla user, por lo que el verbo debería ir relacionado a aquella entidad (en mi humilde opinión)

Comment: Por otro lado, me costó entender tu pregunta....quizás sería bueno que la modificaras para clarificar el punto sin tanto preámbulo.

Comment: @Yussef en tal caso, para por ejemplo eliminar la imagen de perfil, ¿debería hacer uso de la misma api PATCH indicando eliminar o podría mantener mi DELETE sin generar mucha confusión?

Comment: Delete usaría yo, aun cuando la acción en tu DB sea un "update", porque semánticamente me es más claro. Tu eres la persona que está viendo el todo, yo solo puedo responderte en base a lo que me muestras, por esto es difícil dar un concejo. Solo que lo importante es que sea homogéneo, si lo haces de una manera que en las otras partes sea de la misma manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No existe** realmente una **única forma** ni tampoco la más "**correcta**" de hacerlo. Lo importante siempre es poder lugrar buenas `URI`s para que quienes consuman tu `API` les sea intuitivo manejarse. Más allá de toda la documentación que vaya acompañada de la misma, que el path te indique por sí solo a qué apunta, facilita el consumo de la misma.

Nada te impide usar `PUT` obligando a pasar el objeto completo e invalidar el request retornando un status code `4xx` diciendo que tales atributos no se pueden modificar. Sin embargo, no creo que sea lo ideal, siendo que tendrías que agregar validaciones para que no te modifiquen lo que no querés. No lo veo muy escalable en caso de necesitar modificaciones.

Un `PATCH` en `/users` podría darte más flexibilidad y despreocuparte de algunas cosas. Sólo le prestarías atención a los atributos que permitas que se cambien, como en este caso el `displayName` y la `image`. Las `URI`s `users/displayName` (de preferencia personal me gusta más palabras separadas por `-` que usar camel case para las `URL`, es decir `users/display-name`) y `users/profileImage`, podrían ser `PATCH` y servir de "alias" para llamar a `/users` con el objeto que tenga lo que necesitás para hacer el cambio pedido. Por ejemplo podrías tener `users/display-name-and-image` para cambiar display name e image. Es decir como una especie de atajo o request más específico, apuntado a algo en particular. Esta última agrupación podría servirte si sabes que esos dos atributos van a verse afectados en conjunto o mismo podrías considerar que si viene uno vacío ignorar el hacerle update.

Una última opción que podrías explorar, podría ser [Json Patch](https://jsonpatch.com/) aunque creo que podría terminar siendo una sobre ingeniería si no son muchas las operaciones que necesitas aplicar

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta. Si, investigué el JsonPatch pero como comentas para la modificación de dos campos queda en back un código demasiado "sucio", JsonPatch lo aplicaré para objetos que sean totalmente modificables ya que de momento no encontré una forma genérica de restringir los "accesos" a los campos que no quiero que sean modificados con JsonPatch. Si mas adelante me animo a crear alguna anotación o extender la clase para poder añadirle algún objeto request para conseguir esa restricción de manera genérica lo compartiré por aquí.